# No labels in popups in qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I can't seem to find out how to add labels in my popups by using qgis2web.
Where others can add labels to the popup fields (picture below)

[image]

I can only enable or disable popups (picture below). This results in popups with only values, which are difficult to understand without the labels.

[image]

Using QGIS Desktop 3.4.8.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because your layers are in layer groups, which are really poorly supported in qgis2web. If possible, try removing your layers from layer groups, and see if that gives you the options you need.